# copydb - How to create index in background?

Tags: mongodb, locking, database

I'm doing a lot of stuff with big databases in `MongoDB` and sometimes there's a need in making a copy of database where `copydb` command fits perfectly, however it does add global lock for whole `mongod` instance at the end of process for creating index.

I know that there's an argument to create index in background "background:true", but I didn't find such argument for `copydb` command (or `copydatabase`).

Is there way to avoid global lock and force background index creation for Copy Database?

Comment: No, there's no option to create the `copydb` indexes in the background. What's the need for `copydb`?

Comment: Well, having a complete snapshot of database on another mongo server without replication. copydb seems to be the fastest way.

Comment: You should absolutely use replication. Otherwise, you can use [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/). See more about backing up Mongodb in the [MongoDB Manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/).

Comment: But replication means that I have to make a set, but I dont want set, I need one time snapshot without relations between servers. mongodump is definitely an option, but it requires more time than copydb actually. So: make dump, compress to one file, store it somewhere, download on another server, uncompress, import... again leads to index creation when mongod gets globally locked. In copydb its just copying literally directly and index creation, at least process takes less time.

Comment: You can't avoid the index creation. Why would you want to use the server before it has the right indexes in place, anyway? It would be terribly slow.

Comment: I'm okay with index creation in general, but shouldn't it be optional to do it in background? Like create_index or ensure_index do. Global lock for whole mongod instance affects all the rest databases, so thats why I'm asking if there's any possible solution to avoid being locked without response for 5-20 minutes. If it will take more time to create index its fine. Avoiding global lock is kinda priority.

Comment: I think replication is a good choice here if you are constantly trying to sync like this. You can also copy the data files directly, but there's no way to put the index builds in the background for copydb and mongodump.